# Webcam image differ from printed image

Tags: c#, webcam, picturebox, webcam-capture

I am busy with a C# winform software. I use webcam to take a picture which display in a pictureBox.

When I capture the image with the webcam, it captures a zoomed image, and when printing, it is a stretched image. I have tried a variety of `SizeMode` settings.All give the same result

Because I am not sure where the fault is, I will include as much detail as possible:

**Using**

```
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
```

**Selecting Camera:**

```
webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in webcam)
            {
                cmbVideoList.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            }
```

**Using camera (btn click):**

```
cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[cmbVideoList.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
        cam.Start();
        if (cam.IsRunning)
        {
            btnStart.Hide();
        }
        btnStop.Show();

    }
    void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pboxPhoto.Image = bit;
    }
```

**PictureBox size:**

Width: 226

Height: 328

**Printing code:**

```
 PictureBox pict = (PictureBox)pboxPhoto;
        pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pict.Image, 20, 416, 305, 328);
```

Here is a sample of the image on software:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaBc7.png)

Sample of printed image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUaJX.png)

Comment: a PBox Image will always be the raw Image. You could use DrawToBitmap to create a zoomed version or draw with two Rectangles to do any stretching yourself..

Comment: Will try that. Thanks. I am new to C#, do I use DrawToBitMap in the "Printing Code"?

Comment: Yes or whenever the image is ready..

Comment: @TaW I am battling with DrawToBitMap. Can you help me with sample code?

Comment: `using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pboxPhoto.Width, pboxPhoto.Height))
{
    pboxPhoto.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle( Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    //bmp.Save("D:\\patternDraw_.png", ImageFormat.Png);
  // or print it!
}` - Note that if the PBox has a Border you ought to size to `pboxPhoto.ClientSze.Width` etc..

Comment: @TaW Thanks. It worked. If you want to load the code as an answer I will mark it as the selected answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to tell the `PictureBox` to draw itself to a `Bitmap`.

This can be done with all `Controls` and the result will include not just the `Image` and maybe `BackgroundImage` but also anything drawn in the `Paint` event as well as any nested `Controls`.

Here is a simple example:

```
Size sz = pictureBox1.ClientSize;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height))
{
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    // save the image..
    bmp.Save(yourfilepath, ImageFormat.Png);
    // ..or print it!
}
```

A few notes:

- Due to the using clause the `Bitmap` get **disposed** after the last curly, so you would either make use of it inside scope or change to a pattern that disposes of the `Bitmap` at a later point in time.
- The nested `Controls` will be drawn a **reverse** order which will cause problem if they are overlapping!
- Only **nested**, not **overlayed** `Controls` will be included. Since `PictureBox` is not a `Container` (as opposed to e.g. a `Panel`) it won't do to simply placea, say `Label`, over it; instead you need to nest it in code, i.e. make the `PictureBox` its `Parent` and also set a suitable relative `Location`..
- By default the `Bitmap` will have the current machine's screen `dpi` resolution. You cold change it afterwards with `bmp.SetResolution()`..